# FragmentManager when testing non-Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to do testing on classes that are not Activities. I want to test a class which takes as one of its arguments a FragmentManager object, but I can't figure out how to retrieve one.

For example, it also takes a Context object, which I've been able to retrieve with `getInstrumentation().getContext()`, but there doesn't seem to be any sort of analog for FragmentManager. (`getInstrumentation()` can be used as this test class extends InstrumentationTestCase.)

There's a lot of information on testing Activities, but I'm still pretty confused about how to go about testing non-Activities at this point. Any advice will be a huge help.

Comment: Are you trying to Unit test? are you using Robolectric?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test one particular class's behavior. I'm not using Robolectric.

Comment: If you are trying to test one particular class, and not how it integrates with other parts of your application, then I would suggest using a Unit test framework (Robolectric). You can then easily use mocks (look into Mockito), to supply mocks of classes the testing class depends on.

Comment: I'm doing this for a class. We were told we have to use JUnit testing with the built-in Android test classes